# Copy a file from a remote server to windows home using scp

Tags: shell-script, ksh, scp

Is there a way to copy a file from a server to a local folder (i.e. My Documents)? can it be done by `scp`?

I have this script that generate some list. I want this script to automatically copy the generated file to my windows home directory.

I tried this but it just rename the file as the folder it has to be transferred at.

`scp name@some_server:/home/user/file.txt 'somehere\home\home_dir'`

Comment: The only way I can think of that this could be done is to export a directory/file system on the server as a CIFS share, and map that CIFS share as a mapped drive within Windows. What you are asking is much more of a Windows question than Unix/Linux as it will require Windows software that will accept scp connecttions. As such you may get better answers by asking this on Super User.

Comment: Is the script running on the Linux machine or the Windows machine?

Answer (score 2):

You could install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) on your Windows server. If you are trying to push files to your windows host you will need to install and setup cygwin sshd on your windows host.  Or you could just pull files to your windows host.

Comment: Installing cygwin sshd has a clear advantage (at least in my opinion), you will be using a widely-used sofware (sshd), so getting help and tips should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

Other possible approach is export a windows share at your windows host (how to to that would be off-topic) and then access it from your linux host using SMB tools like `smbclient`.